# Update expiration in node Redis without affecting the key or value

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I've looked through material quite a bit for node redis, and I'm surprised I haven't found anything.

I set the record like so:

```
redis.set(key, value, 'EX', REDIS_CACHE_CACHE_TTL)
```

But there are situations when I want to update the TTL expiration without having to delete the key and recreating; is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you set the key the TTL will be removed(equal to -1). I think if you run the SET for the key-value that already exists with the new TTL value, the key-value will be the same but the TTL is updated.

In Redis will be something like:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET HELLO WORLD EX 3000
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL HELLO
(integer) 2991
127.0.0.1:6379> SET HELLO WORLD EX 100
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL HELLO
(integer) 97
127.0.0.1:6379>
```